# Make Discord BOT get random image from a ftp server (Filezilla)

Tags: python, ftp, discord, filezilla

I'm just gonna say it right away that I have no experience whatsoever in python. I'm trying to make a bot for a private Discord server that posts a random image (.jpg) from a ftp server (root directory) after typing '$gimme'. #file names are random jibberish

I've searched for hours to find a solution but I always get stuck at something. I can't figure out the syntax of ftp in conjunction with discord since my knowledge of python is as close to non-existent as it gets and no matter how much I search for an answer I can't figure it out.

This is really my last option, I have nowhere else to look for. I hope someone with a little bit more knowledge than me can help me out.

Thank You

```
import os
import requests
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import random

client = discord.Client()

ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(os.getenv('BOP_IP'), 2021)
ftp.login(os.getenv('BOP_UN'), os.getenv('BOP_PW'))

#path='/'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
  .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('$gimme'):
    await message.channel.send(#######)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT with the callback method**

I know python and FTP not discord but by looking at the docs I found how to send a file in discord. I made the following code (without test). I add a function which randomly get a file from FTP the server and call this function in the on_message function

```
import os
import requests
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import random
import discord

client = discord.Client()

ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(os.getenv('BOP_IP'), 2021)
ftp.login(os.getenv('BOP_UN'), os.getenv('BOP_PW'))

#path='/'
def download_random_file()
  file_list = ftp.nlst()
  random_file_name = random.choice(file_list)
  #download the file
  with open(random_file_name, 'wb') as fp:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(random_file_name), fp.write) 
    
  return random_file_name

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
  .format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('$gimme'):
    file_downloaded = download_random_file()
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(file_downloaded))
    os.unlink(file_downloaded) #Delete the downloaded file

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

To optimize :

- Ensure the file is downloaded (with try catch block)
- Ensure the downloaded file is an image (with the MIMETYPE)

Answer (score 0):

@axelinux

Thank you, again.

The revised code you've sent me returned the following after typing '$gimme' in discord:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 34, in on_message
    file_downloaded = download_random_file()
  File "main.py", line 20, in download_random_file
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(random_file_name), fp.write)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 425, in retrbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 382, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 348, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 275, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 248, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 File not found
```

I've done some search and I think I have it working now:

```
def download_random_repo():
 ftp.cwd('/repo')
 file_list = ftp.nlst()
 random_file_name = random.choice(file_list)
 ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(random_file_name), open(random_file_name, 'wb').write) #download the file
 return random_file_name
```

All I had to do was changing the line to: ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(random_file_name), open(random_file_name, 'wb').write)

Thank you so much for your help. Wouldn't have it working without you :)